# animate parents width on child *ngIf

Tags: html, css, angular

I'd like to animate the parent container's width when the child components appear/disappear on `*ngIf`

I know how to animate the child on `*ngIf`, which I have set up already:

```
animations: [loadingEnter]
```

```
loadingEnter = trigger('loadingEnter', [
  transition(':enter', [
    style({ opacity: 0 }),
    animate('300ms', style({ opacity: 1 })),
  ]),
]);
```

```
<div class="parent">
  <div *ngIf="myCondition"></div>
  <div *ngIf="!myCondition"></div>
</div>
```

The child animates properly, but id like to have the parent grow smoothly when the children appear/disappear.

The children have dynamic widths, so I can't set the parent width and transition css on width.

Any ideas?

Comment: post a stackblitz if possible